# Queries with Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm working with rails and I have this sql query I would like to do with arel.

```
"SELECT `people`.* FROM `peoples`  WHERE `peoples`.`home_id` = 289 AND (`people`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2013-03-12' AND '2013-03-15' AND (`people`.`first_name` LIKE '%jane%' OR `people`.`email` LIKE '%jane%'))"
```

Now, I have solved the query with arel but i would like to avoid repeating the "matches("%#{search}%")" for attributes that must match the same search variable.

```
a.where(a.arel_table[:created_at].in(date_range).and(a.arel_table[:first_name].matches("%#{search}%").or(a.arel_table[:email].matches("%#{search}%"))))
```

Something like:

```
a.where(a.arel_table[:created_at].in(date_range).and([:email, :first_name].each {|attr| or.(a.arel_table[:attr].matches("%#{search}%"))))
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the condition looks like (((c1 or c2) or c3) or c4) but it seem to be that Arel's conception of "or" is binary.

So it's no possible to define them as (c1 or c2 or c3 or c4).